# Add "useLibrary" to build.gradle in android cordova plugin

Tags: android, cordova, cordova-plugins, build.gradle

I'm developing a cordova plugin. In this plugin I use the library `org.apache.http.legacy`. I copy this library successfully in my lib folder. But I need to write `useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'` in my build.gradle file.

How can I do this?

My plugin.xml:

```
[...]

<platform name="android">
    <config-file target="AndroidManifest.xml" parent="/manifest/application">
        <activity android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|locale" android:label="DownloaderActivity" android:launchMode="singleTop" android:name="[pluginPath].DownloaderActivity" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.DeviceDefault.NoActionBar" android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan">
        </activity>
        <service android:name="[pluginPath].DownloaderService" />
        <receiver android:name="d[pluginPath].DownloaderServiceBroadcastReceiver" />
    </config-file>

    <config-file target="AndroidManifest.xml" parent="/manifest">
        <uses-permission android:name="com.android.vending.CHECK_LICENSE" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>
    </config-file>

    <config-file target="res/xml/config.xml" parent="/*">
        <feature name="ExpansionFileReader">
            <param name="android-package" value="[pluginPath].ExpansionFileReader" />
        </feature>
    </config-file>

    <source-file src="src/android/ExpansionFileReader.java" target-dir="src/de/[path]/cordova/plugin" />
    <source-file src="src/android/expansion" target-dir="src/de/[path]/cordova/plugin" />
    <source-file src="src/android/zipfile" target-dir="src/de/[path]/cordova/plugin" />
    <source-file src="src/com" target-dir="src" />
    <source-file src="src/android/org.apache.http.legacy.jar" target-dir="libs" framework="true" />

    <framework src="com.google.http-client:google-http-client-android:+" />
    <framework src="com.google.api-client:google-api-client-android:+" />
    <framework src="com.google.api-client:google-api-client-gson:+" />
    <framework src="com.google.code.gson:gson:2.2.4" />
</platform>
[...]
```

I tried to use `<framework src="src/gradle/buildExtension.gradle" custom="true" type="gradleReference" />`, where `buildExtension.gradle` contains

```
android {
    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
}
```

But it didn't work. The framework tags don't work either, by the way.

Does anyone has a solution for this?

Comment: I have the same problem, did you find a solution for this?

Comment: I think it was the solution I just posted. Hope it helps. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

This could have been the solution:

I added a build-extras.gradle file that adds the gradle part:

plugin.xml:

```
[...]
<source-file src="src/android/ExpansionFileReader.java" target-dir="src/de/projektionisten/cordova/plugin" />
<source-file src="src/android/expansion" target-dir="src/de/projektionisten/cordova/plugin" />
<source-file src="src/android/zipfile" target-dir="src/de/projektionisten/cordova/plugin" />
<source-file src="src/com" target-dir="src" />

<source-file src="src/android/build-extras.gradle" target-dir="CordovaLib" />
<source-file src="src/android/org.apache.http.legacy.jar" target-dir="libs" framework="true" />
<framework src="src/android/build-extras.gradle" custom="true" type="gradleReference" />
[...]
```

build-extras.gradle:

```
android {
    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
}
```